# Django -- Redirecting Views with Parameters

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

In the Django app I am building I would like to have the user creation process go as follows: As user signs up, if valid is then redirected to create a LIST object, and if valid is then redirected to what will be a dashboard for the LIST object just created. My views.py are as follows:

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UserSignupForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            g = Group.objects.get(name='test_group')
            g.user_set.add(user)
            # log user in
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, u'Welcome to Social FollowUp')
            return redirect('user_create')
    else:
        form = forms.UserSignupForm()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'user_signup.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

@login_required
@permission_required('')
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_form = forms.ListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            list_create = list_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'List {0} created'.format(list_create.list_id))
            return redirect('user_dashboard')
    else:
        list_form = forms.ListForm()

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/create.html', {'list_form': list_form, })

def user_dashboard(request, list_id):
try:
    list_id = models.List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
except models.List.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/view.html', {'list_id': list_id})
```

My urls.py for these views is as follows:

```
url(r'user/signup/$', views.user_signup, name='user_signup'),
url(r'u/dashboard/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
url(r'u/list/create/$', views.user_create, name='user_create'),
```

When I try to run through the process, the first two views work correctly. However when I redirect to the user_dashboard I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'user_dashboard' with arguments '' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

which sites this:

```
return redirect('user_dashboard')
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with me not passing in a list_id, however, even when I tried to pass in a hardcoded value it did not work (like this):

```
return redirect('user_dashboard', {'list_id': 2})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
return redirect(reverse('user_dashboard', args=(2,)))
```

Your code

```
return redirect('user_dashboard')
```

would not work because in your url pattern, you have

```
url(r'u/dashboard/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
```

which **requires** `list_id` as a parameter.

Comment: I just tried that and it returned Reverse for 'user_dashboard' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'args': (2,)}' not found.

Comment: oops.. :) i completely forgot the `reverse` :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `redirect(reverse(...))` because [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) accepts both `args` and `kwargs` and passes them to `reverse`. So: `redirect('user_dashboard', list_id=2)` should work.

Comment: With the reverse included it redirects. Now lets say I don't want to hardcode this with 2, and I want it to be the list_id for the given user. Do I simply create a local variable called lets say `list_id` and then pass that variable into `args=()`?

Comment: Yes. You can just replace 2 with list_id which is the local variable

Comment: Sure, you should be able to do something like `redirect('user_dashboard', YOUR_VARIABLE)` or `redirect('user_dashboard', list_id=YOUR_VARIABLE)` since it accepts `*args` and `**kwargs`