# Django redirect to another view

Tags: django

I have small problem with redirecting from one view to another according to [Django topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Already read some answers like: [ans_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328810/django-redirect-to-view), [ans_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865732/django-redirecting-views-with-parameters), [ans_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614172/how-can-i-redirect-from-view-in-django/42614265), but can't find solution.

Instead get an error:

```
Reverse for 'add_tasks_continue' not found. 'add_tasks_continue' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**Goal:** redirect from one view to another with some data.

My view functions:

```
def add_day_tasks(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        return redirect('add_tasks_continue', data=locals())

def add_tasks_continue(request, data):
    ...
    return render(request, 'eventscalendar/add_task_continue.html', locals())
```

My url:

```
app_name = 'calendar'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', calendar),
    url(r'^calendar/add_day_task/$', add_day_tasks),
    url(r'^calendar/add_task_continue/$', add_tasks_continue, name='add_tasks_continue'),
]
```

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Why do you pass `data`? Your URL does not expect that. (And in future please state exactly what problem you are having, target than "can't find solution".)

Comment: @DanielRoseman the data is a dictionary [description updated]. With this method i need still pass regex patterns into url?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi: there is no builtin path converter for a dictionary, and likely there will not be one in the (near) future. URLs are not a good way to transfer such amounts of data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the how to transfer data from one view to another?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi: you usually do not do that. Usually urls and GET and POST data are used to transfer *small* amounts of (usually scalar) data. Items that need to persist are stored in a database. Using `locals()` is by the way not a good idea either: how would you transfer a generic object?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep you right i get brain lag :P

Answer (score 0):

Since `add_tasks_continue(request, data)` has a parameter "data", `(?P<data>…)` is expected in your url. That is the point. 
It could be
    `url(r'^calendar/add_task_continue/(?P<data>[a-z]+)$', add_tasks_continue, name='add_tasks_continue')`
or else
`url(r'^calendar/add_task_continue/(?P<data>\d+)$', add_tasks_continue, name='add_tasks_continue')`.
However, you should keep in mind that url are strings, so "data" is supposed to be a string as it appears in the url.